# ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted']

Tags: python, random-forest, xgboost

I'm working on Multiclass Classification and I'm finding accuracies of classifiers, I’m using:

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=2)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = model.predict(X_test)
Accuracy=accuracy_score(y_test, preds, average='micro')
```

Getting an error:

```
TypeError: accuracy_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'average'
```

and when I'm using:

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=2)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = model.predict(X_test)
Accuracy=accuracy_score(y_test, preds)
```

Getting an error:

```
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].
```

Can anyone please help me with how can I find the accuracy for the Multiclass Classification problem?

Below the code I have in my function for xgboost:

```
scorers = {
        'f1_score':make_scorer(f1_score),
        'precision_score': make_scorer(precision_score),
        'recall_score': make_scorer(recall_score),
        'accuracy_score': make_scorer(accuracy_score)
      }
#fitting the training dataset to the model
xgb_model = XGBClassifier(n_jobs=-1, objective='multi:softmax')
#setattr(xgb_model, 'verbosity', 2)
param_dist = {'n_estimators': stats.randint(150, 1000),
              'learning_rate': stats.uniform(0.01, 0.59),
              'subsample': stats.uniform(0.3, 0.6),
              'max_depth': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
              'colsample_bytree': stats.uniform(0.5, 0.4),
              'min_child_weight': [1, 2, 3, 4]
             }

#     numFolds = 5
#     kfold_5 = cross_validation.KFold(n = len(X), shuffle = True, n_folds = numFolds)
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle = True)
    gridCV = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb_model, 
                             param_distributions = param_dist,
                             cv = skf,  
                             n_iter = 5,  
                             scoring = scorers, 
                             verbose = 3, 
                             n_jobs = -1,
                             return_train_score=True,
                             refit = False)
gridCV.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Here is the error when trying `make_scorer(f1_score,average='micro')`:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-8b24047fa926> in <module>
      1 print("********** Xgboost classifier *************")
      2 start_time = time.monotonic()
----> 3 y_test, xgb_predict, xgb_pred_prob = xgboost_classifier(x,y)
      4 end_time = time.monotonic()
      5 print(timedelta(seconds=end_time - start_time))

<ipython-input-67-2661dd9c3c1a> in xgboost_classifier(x, y)
     36     scorers = {
     37             'f1_score':make_scorer(f1_score,average='micro'),
---> 38             'precision_score': make_scorer(precision_score()),
     39             'recall_score': make_scorer(recall_score()),
     40             'accuracy_score': make_scorer(accuracy_score())

TypeError: precision_score() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y_true' and 'y_pred'
```

I don't know why `gridCV.fit(x_train, y_train)` does not feed `Y` values to scorers?

Comment: `accuracy_score` should have no keyword argument `average`, that's true. Are you sure your second error message comes from the `accuracy_score` function? I would expect this error for something like the `F1_score` if you have multiple classes and forgot to set the average keyword. What version of `sklearn` are you using? Can you give us the whole error stack output?

Comment: here is the whole code I'm using, I've tested with accuracy to check if it came from it or no

Sklearn version is 0.22.1

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem by adding average to F1, precision and recall. It's only accuracy which does not need this argument !

```
scorers = {
            'f1_score': make_scorer(f1_score, average='micro'),
            'precision_score': make_scorer(precision_score, average='micro'),
            'recall_score': make_scorer(recall_score, average='micro'),
            'accuracy_score': make_scorer(accuracy_score)
          }
```

Comment: Edit your question. This section is for **answers**. This post will be deleted, as it is against site's rules to post non-answers in answers section.

Comment: Thanks, if you want to add something to your question, please use the 'Edit' function.

Comment: This might be the problem: `make_scorer(f1_score)`. You have to pass any keyword arguments to the `make_scorer` as well. Can you try `make_scorer(f1_score,average='micro')`.

Comment: Thank you, I cant edit my question, this is why I posted again.